# Can I use a multiple-entry Schengen visa for business and tourism?

Tags: europe, multiple-entry, schengen-visas

I have a multiple-entry Schengen visa for 90 days and a validity of 3 years. It was issued by Germany. I have traveled to Germany 3 times prior to this and on this visa I have traveled once to Germany for business. Now I want to do a Europe trip in December from India.

- Do I need to apply for a visa again?
- In case the Schengen visa is issued by Germany, do I have to do enter in Germany first and then travel to other countries?
- Can I enter other countries and then travel to Germany?

Comment: You two last question were definitely answered on this site, so you might want to use search. To answer the first question you haven't give enough information. Will your visa still be valid in December? How many days have you already spend in Germany.

Comment: i have spent 14 days from the 90 days and the visa is valid till 2020.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- You don't need a new visa if you didn't reach 90 days continuously and your visa is still valid.
- You REALLY don't need to enter Germany first, but it's BETTER to do so. Because immigration clearance might be a bit easier, like they won't ask why you come and how long you will stay before you go to Germany.
- Yes you can enter other countries, as long as the country accepts your visa.

Comment: what does the 90 days mean here. does it mean 90 days max per visit ? or Does it mean 90 days max in total  3 years?

Comment: @Mitz See https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/13183/how-does-the-schengen-90-180-rule-work

Comment: @Mitz It means you are allowed to stay for 90 days for every 180 days, count continuously from the day you enter the country

Comment: @Binh, I think the 90/180-rule should be characterized differently. You must meet it *every day* and not the first day.